# Disable memusage extension for scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted

When trying to run a custom scraper, I get the following error:

```
  File "/home/barfoo/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scrapy/extensions/memusage.py", line 16, in <module>
    from scrapy.mail import MailSender
  File "/home/barfoo/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scrapy/mail.py", line 23, in <module>
    from twisted.mail.smtp import ESMTPSenderFactory
ImportError: No module named 'twisted.mail'
```

Although both `Twisted` and `scrapy` are part of the `requirements.txt`:

```
Twisted==15.5.0
scrapy==1.0.0
```

(installed with `env/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt`)

Looking for help online did not result in a quick fix. Nevertheless `memusage` is not necessary. Is there a way to disable the extension in the spider itself or in the `main`?

Answer (score 2):

You can disable `memusage` by disabling it in the `settings.py` file of scrapy. Like this:
`MEMUSAGE_ENABLED = False`

Comment: The problem is that it is not a scrapy project: it is a python file that makes use of the `scrapy` library. Is there a way to do this without a scrapy project?

Comment: I noticed you are using `python 3.4`. Referring to this http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html I would suggest to use python 2.7 as Python 3.4 is not yet supported by scrapy.